# Java helper method in recursive function to read string

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having an issue with adding a helper method in my already working recursive function using only 2 parameters, when adding the 3rd (the helper method) my code breaks and looking towards a solution. The program uses a scanner for keyboard input for a string, another input for a character, then outputs the number of occurrences of the letter. The error occurs on the second if statement and both return statements. After the second keyboard input I'm getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class recursiveString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a character to find number of occurences: ");
        char character = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(character + " occurred " + count(input, character, input.length() - 1) + " times.");

    }

    public static int count(String str, char a, int high) {

        if (str.length() == high) // set equal to high to stop the recursion from infinitely looping
            return high;
        if (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) != a) // if the character in the string is  not equal to "a" subtract from count(substring)
            return count(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), a, high - 1);
        else 
            return 1 + count(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), a, high - 1); 
            // else add +1 to count for each instance of "a" in the string

    }

}
```

Comment: Please think about the following: An empty String will lead to what if you call `str.length() - 1` ? And then think about when you stop recursion, obviously, you call `count` even with the empty String

Comment: The string comes from the scanner correct and takes the length of the input and minuses 1 from that? I had no issues with the last program, it's when I add the helper method using a 3rd parameter.

Comment: Pen + paper with a small String `aba` should show you the issue - sometimes this old school debugging works fast enough. Otherwise, any IDE has a debugger, this allows for going through  the program execution

Comment: Don't forget, to look at the description and nature of the Java `substring` method. It's end-exclusive

Comment: What's the purpose of high? If you start it off as one less than the length of the string and keep reducing it in each step, it will never equal the length of the string and the recursion will fail once the string is empty. You might as well just use 0 as an end condition.

Comment: It's a programming exercise from my java book, the first program does the same thing with only 2 parameters and using 0 as end condition as you said and it worked fine. This program wants me to rewrite that program using a 3rd parameter (the helper method, int high).                                      Edit: I see what you mean use 0 for the first  return? But how do I incorporate high into the function?

Comment: Why is the int 'high' described as a helper method? Is it supposed to be a product of an actual method?

Comment: @Devin, I added an answer in which high makes some sense. Note that it works only if high = input.length(), otherwise the check is partial.

Comment: Thank you it works using that, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, that may help you avoid an index out of bounds:

```
public static int count(String str, char a, int high) {

    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
    // just to be extra safe, if we have an empty string or null 
        return 0;

    }
    //changed this end condition - now high describes how many steps we take before returning the answer
    if (high == 0) // to stop the recursion from infinitely looping
        return high;
    if (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) != a) // if the last character in the string is not equal to "a" subtract from count(substring)
        return count(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), a, high - 1);
    else 
        return 1 + count(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), a, high - 1); 
        // else add +1 to count for each instance of "a" in the string

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the design of recursive methods: first off, you should focus on a problem and define it for the base case, or cases if there are more than one.

My view on this problem is that the base case is the empty string (but even before that, assure it isn't `null`) or if `high` is set to 0.

My understanding of `high` is that you'd use it to set how many characters of the string you want to check for the occurrence of the character `a`; it would have been more straight-forward to check as the string grows bigger, givin `high` the meaning of search occurrences of character `a` into the `str.substring(0,high)`, but I tried to keep it similar to your code.

```
//we'll use high to "tell" the count method how many characters it will consider into the occurrences from the end of the given string
public static int count(String str, char a, int high) {
    //if the string isn't valid or high just tells it to stop, return 0 as there can be no occurrences of a in str
    if(str == null || str.equals("") || high == 0)
      return 0;

    // if the last character in the string is not equal to a, let's just shrink the string
    if (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) != a)
        return count(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), a, high - 1);

    // otherwise add this 1 occurrence to the ones it will find in the rest of the string
    else 
        return 1 + count(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), a, high - 1); 
}
```

The call in the `main` would then be:

```
System.out.println(character+ " occurred " + count(input, character, input.length()) + " times.");
```